# Preciso desenvolver um programa que dado um arquivo de entrada, gere um arquivo de saída em java

Tags: java

Dado um arquivo de entrada, gere um arquivo de saída como mostrado abaixo

```
Arquivo de Entrada  |  Arquivo de Saida
--------------------+--------------------
1                   |  impar
2                   |  par
3                   |  impar
4                   |  par
5                   |  impar
6                   |  par
```

Consegui apenas ler o arquivo txt e separar os pares dos impares
queria saber como criar o arquivo de saída com o impar par, impar etc sem ter que separá-los

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Questao1
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try 
        { 
            FileReader arquivo = new FileReader("Entrada1.txt"); 
            BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(arquivo);

            String linha = leitor.readLine();
            String pares = "";
            String impares = "";
            while (linha != null) 
            {
                int numero = Integer.parseInt(linha);
                if (numero % 2 == 0){
                   pares += numero + "\n";
                } else{  
                    impares += numero + "\n";
                }

            linha = leitor.readLine();
             }
            leitor.close();
                System.out.println(pares);
                System.out.println(impares);
        } 



        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz aqui uma implementação, o programa vai ler o arquivo, analisar e converter os dados e escrever o arquivo com a formatação indicada na sua pergunta.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Os arquivos de entrada e saida.
        String inputFilename = "input.txt";
        String outputFilename = "output.txt";

        // Lista de entrada.
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        // Abre o arquivo de entrada.
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename))) {
            String line;
            // Ler linha por linha.
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                // Adiciona cada linha na lista lines.
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Lista de saida.
        List<String> outputLines = new ArrayList<>();

        // Ler cada item da lista lines.
        for (String line : lines) {
            // Converte o item para int.
            int numberInLine = Integer.parseInt(line);

            // Verifica se numberInLine é par ou impar e atribui o resultado a data.
            String data = numberInLine % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "impar";

            // Adiciona data na lista de saida.
            outputLines.add(data);
        }

        // Abre o arquivo de saida.
        try (BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilename))) {
            buffer.write("Arquivo de Entrada  |  Arquivo de Saida  ");
            buffer.newLine();

            buffer.write("--------------------+--------------------");
            buffer.newLine();

            // Faz um loop na lista lines.
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                // Escreve cada item na lista lines e outputLines com uma formatação de espaços em branco.
                buffer.write(String.format("%-20s|  %-18s", lines.get(i), outputLines.get(i)));
                // Adiciona uma nova quebra de linha.
                buffer.newLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exemplo**

Arquivo de entrada:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Arquivo de saída:

```
Arquivo de Entrada  |  Arquivo de Saida  
--------------------+--------------------
0                   |  par               
1                   |  impar             
2                   |  par               
3                   |  impar             
4                   |  par               
5                   |  impar             
6                   |  par               
7                   |  impar             
8                   |  par               
9                   |  impar
```